# How to get previous 6 months date from current date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying get last six months date from current date .

```js
var d = new Date();
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
alert(months[d.getMonth()-6]);
```

but i am getting `udefined`

Comment: `d.getMonth()` right now is `4` that minus `6` is `-2`.

Comment: @Roland Starke :so how to get date?

Answer (score 8):

I always recommend using date libraries to assist in these types of calculations. One of the most popular with a ton of support and examples is moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)

To get six months ago from the current date using moment is:

```
moment().subtract(6, 'months')
```

and then to print the month name would be:

```
moment().subtract(6, 'months').format('MMMM')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your code like below-

```
var d = new Date();
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);
  console.log(months[d.getMonth()]);
```

We need to get Month from date object the set to back (with - 6) then get it back.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var d = new Date();
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
var monthName = months[new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6)).getMonth()];
console.log(monthName)
```